# Spectral sequence for a truncated semi cosimplicial space

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, spectral-sequences

Consider the simplicial indexing category $\Delta$. Now, let's denote the subcategory consisting of injections as $\Delta_{inj}$. When we're dealing with a cosimplicial space, which is essentially a functor $C: \Delta \to \text{Spaces}$, we get a Bousfield-Kan spectral sequence. This spectral sequence is associated with the Tot tower and converges to the homotopy limit of the cosimplicial space $C$.

Question:  Is there a similar spectral sequence when we replace $\Delta$ with the subcategory $\Delta_{inj, \leq n}$, where $\Delta_{inj, \leq n}$ is obtained by truncating $\Delta_{inj}$ at level $n$. Any suggestions or references would be great! Thank you in advance.